P-51, P-82; how about a P-113 or beyond?
The P-82 improved on the P-51 in range
and slightly in top speed, at the expense of cruise speed and service ceiling.
This was helped by lengthening the fuselages for more fuel tanks, and by changing the engine and propeller.
How might a triple (or quadruple?) Mustang like the imaginary one pictured behave aerodynamically?
Which laws of diminishing returns would apply?
Ignore its operational role and weaponry.
(Were any manned triple fuselage airplanes ever built, not just proposed?)


I would guess that the drag increase would be non-linear, and would cross the "good idea threshold" pretty quickly...

The Rutan Voyager has three fuselages.

Wasn't the Voyager notoriously unstable in flight?  Not saying that's specifically due to the fuselages, just that the Voyager isn't exactly a good place to look if you want to see the Good Idea Threshold, because it was designed to meet one very specific and extreme goal which was, arguably, not a Good Idea.

Two aircraft spring to mind powered by four Merlins, the Avro Lancaster and the Handley Page Halifax. What does that tell you about the likely handling of a aircraft with four heavy piston engines?

Voyager is usually described as twin-boom, like the P-38.

At some point it's just becoming silly.

But what kind of silly?  Exactly how and when does it cross the good idea threshold?

A P-113, huh? Really? P-113?

Fighters are great, but it may be time to look into bombers, cargo transports, or airliners if you like long range multiengine aircraft.
However, the load distribution has merit in your design.
One might just put fuel tanks and engines out on the wings, with a larger central fuselage that has space for a bathroom (critical in long flights).
This one, and the 707 can cruise much faster and higher, and this one had greater range.

So is the question's answer then "like a B-36 or B-47 or 707"?

@CamilleGoudeseune i did consider an elongated nacelle behind the engines for fuel rather than underslung tanks.  The design is possible aerodynamicly but is impractical.
